# Design a Push Down Automata to count the number of characters

Tags: context-free-grammar, turing-machines, pushdown-automaton

The Alphabet: a, b, c
I'm trying to define a PDA which accepts

```
 a^n b^m c^p : n + p = 2k for some integer k, m = k, and n, m, p, k >= 0
```

I think some strings that would be accepted are: #abc#; #aabbcc#; #aaabbbccc#; #abbccc#; #aaabbc# etc
The number of a's, b's and c's are not necessarily equal.

Start the head of the push down automata on the black space that is right most.

Usually I write my PDAs in columns:

```
State:    Symbol Read:    Next State:    Head Instruction:    
s         #               r1             Left
r1        c               r2             #
```

and so on...

Comment: a^n b^n c^n - You are correct. #cab# is not acceptable

Comment: Am I misreading this, or is `m` an unnecessary alias for `k`?

Comment: Nope, I believe you are reading that correct

Comment: @Bobby: I edited your question to be more consistent with your update to the language definition. I hope I haven't misunderstood your meaning, if so feel free to roll back.

Comment: @Jim: Thanks, I didn't see those strings, thanks.  This is still not a context free language though correct?

Comment: @Bobby: Still not CF, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the language you describe is not context-free, and therefore cannot be
recognized with a PDA.  The problem is that you need to enforce a constraint
(n+p = 2m) that spans an arbitrarily long substring, yet is not allowed to "pump" (when
attempting to construct a proof using the pumping lemma for context-free languages).

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you.  I will show via the pumping lemma that this is not context-free.

Answer (score 2):

```
M=(K, E, q0, F, delta, stack_alphabet)
K={q0,q1,q2}
E={a,b,c,z}
F={q2}
stack_alphabet={a,b,z}
delta=
{
 *pop*     *push*
(q0, e, e)(q1, z)
(q1, a, e)(q1, a)
(q1, b, a)(q1, e)
(q1, b, z)(q1, bz)
(q1, c, b)(q2, e)
(q2, c, b)(q2, e)
}
```